# Symfony error when creating entity : Warning: mkdir(): File exists

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mkdir

I'm working on a Symfony project since 3 weeks. I'd created 2 entities without any problems. But today, I've got an error with the doctrine:generate:entity command, at the end of execution, i've this message :

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Warning: mkdir(): File exists

I cleaned the cache, with the command and manually..

If anyone could help me..

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure

1. you have successful rights
2. no issue in duplicated code (e.g. when you copy&paste existing entity into a new one and forgot to replace all code/annotations etc.)
3. Other then that I found that mkdir() is not called safe for concurrency, so that means that some other process might have already created the directory. I openend an issue on Github for the Doctrine Bundle, which you can follow here: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/580

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this myself after composer-updating this morning.

Locking the sensio/generator bundle to the previous version seems to have fixed things for now:

```
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "3.0.10"
}
```

I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/523) on the Sensio Bundle to see whether this is a regression or something deeper.

Answer (score 0):

try this, doctrine:generate:entity --no-debug

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be accepted and upvoted. Adding a little context and formatting will help.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here after updating sensio/generator-bundle from version v3.0.11 to 3.1.0 on Windows 10.

Removing 3.1.0 and installing 3.0.11 solved the problem for the moment.

https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/524

Comment: You right ! I've downgrade on 3.0.11 and it works properly again. Thank you